# OTL4.0 otl_stream bind issues

Tags: binding, otl

i have a question regarding the binding of variables using the otl_stream.
No matter how i bind, using indexed or naming the order/naming does not affect which column is being updated. It seems always sequential.

You can see that in `otl_stream` the column-names have been switched. However
the postgres DB shows that both inserts yield equal results.

1. OS:Windows
2. OTL:4.0
3. Visual Studio 2013.
4. Platform: x64
5. ODBC: PostgreSQL ANSI(x64) 9.03.04.00

Any ideas?
Kind Regards Auke-Dirk

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

// #define OTL_ODBC_UNIX // uncomment this line if UnixODBC is used
#define OTL_ODBC_ALTERNATE_RPC
#if !defined(_WIN32) && !defined(_WIN64)
#define OTL_ODBC
#else 
#define OTL_ODBC_POSTGRESQL // required with PG ODBC on Windows
#endif

#include "otlv4_h2\otlv4.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    otl_connect db;

    otl_connect::otl_initialize(); // initialize ODBC environment
    try{

        db.rlogon("Driver=PostgreSQL ANSI;Server=localhost;Database=Horus;UID=postgres;PWD=12odsc7a");

        otl_cursor::direct_exec
            (
            db,
            "drop table test_tab",
            otl_exception::disabled // disable OTL exceptions
            ); // drop table

        db.commit();

        otl_cursor::direct_exec
            (
            db,
            "create table test_tab(f1 int, f2 int)"
            );  // create table

        db.commit();

        otl_stream ostr1(1, // no buffers
            "insert into test_tab values(:f1<int>,:f2<int>)",
            db
            );
        ostr1 << 1 << 2;
        db.commit();

        otl_stream ostr2(1, // no buffers
            "insert into test_tab values(:f2<int>,:f1<int>)",
            db
            );
        ostr2 << 1 << 2;
        db.commit();
    }
    catch (otl_exception& p){ // intercept OTL exceptions
        cerr << p.msg << endl; // print out error message
        cerr << p.stm_text << endl; // print out SQL that caused the error
        cerr << p.sqlstate << endl; // print out SQLSTATE message
        cerr << p.var_info << endl; // print out the variable that caused the error
    }

    db.logoff(); // disconnect from ODBC

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Could not resolve this issue and therefor moved on to soci.

Regards